# GSM900A module is not connecting to the network

Tags: arduino-uno, power, gsm

My GSM900A module is not connecting to the network. IT continuously blinks(1 sec). The power was given by the Arduino Uno board. Then I tried connecting an external battery(4.2V , 4200mAH). But it didn't work. What kind of a solution would be suitable for this issue?

Comment: maybe there is no network to connect to

Comment: Maybe you don't live in an area with the right frequency bands for the SIM900A to operate. Does your country even *have* a GSM network any more? Many don't now. It's old technology. You should be using an LTE modem nowadays.

Comment: gsm network is still available in our country.